# Why Standard Deviation equal to 0 by GLM prediction?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, generalized-linear-model, standard-deviation

### This is my dataset:

```
library(NHANES)
library(plyr)

# Generate an example dataset 
myvars <- c("ID","Gender", "Age", "Diabetes","BPSysAve", "BPDiaAve")
nhanes <- as.data.frame(NHANESraw[myvars])
nhanes$age.range <- cut(nhanes$Age, breaks = c(-Inf,45, 65, Inf), labels = c("<45Yrs", "45-65Yrs", ">65Yrs"))
```

### Let's fit a simple GLM with SBP as dependent variable:

```
# Fitting the GLM model
fit <- glm(BPSysAve ~ Diabetes + age.range, data = nhanes)
```

### Producing predicted SBP:

```
# Producing df with predictions
pred <- data.frame(diabetes = fit$model$Diabetes, 
                  sbp = predict.glm(fit, type = "response"),
                  age.range = fit$model$age.range)
```

### Summarizing SBP prediction by strata:

```
# Summarize prediction
ddply(pred, c("diabetes", "age.range"), summarize,
              N = sum(!is.na(sbp)),
              sbp.mean = mean(sbp),
              sd = sd(sbp)
              )
```

### Exploring results:

```
 diabetes    age.range     N    sbp.mean    sd
1       No    <45Yrs      8616   110.6067    0
2       No  45-65Yrs      2942   124.9528    0
3       No    >65Yrs      1701   133.2779    0
4      Yes    <45Yrs       214   113.6860    0
5      Yes  45-65Yrs       742   128.0321    0
6      Yes    >65Yrs       645   136.3572    0
```

### I would like to understand:

1. Is my approach correct for achieving fitted SBP and SD across the above mentioned strata?
2. Why fitted SBP means were the same?

Comment: @Borexino I am deleting my answer.  If this is how people are downvoting for clear answers, what can I say.  what do you expect to find `sd(c(15, 15, 15))` i.e. when all values of a group are same

Comment: @akrun No idea of downvoting!! Could you please explain to me why I had same mean per groups?

Comment: I didn't see the answer by @akrun, but surely if you are predicting SBP based on two categorical variables like diabetes and age, then the predicted SBP will be identical for all patients with the same combinations of predictor variables, therefore the s.d. of the predictions within each group will be 0. If you want the mean and s.d. of the SBP by group you need to dplyr the original data, not the predicted data. If akrun undeletes his answer, I'll upvote it.